# Is there a build in functionality in .NET to create thread bound variables?

Tags: .net, multithreading, scope, transactionscope, named-scope

Is there a way to do this (psedo code):

```
GetCurrentThread().Items.Add(new RefObject);
```

then later on retrive it

```
RefObject[] refObjs = GetCurrentThread().Items;
```

and enumerate the objects. Obviously both calls will occur on the same thread during the life span of it.

The basic idea is that I can easisly identify the items for the current thread were and that they are in fact created in this thread. It's same as using the `Page.Request` object for an ASP.NET request - you know it's very unique in the worker process, so it doesn't get mixed up with other requests being served at the same time. I want to treat a thread like `Page.Request` - it comes and then goes, but while it's alive, I can query it at will without caring about other threats that exist in the process.

Once I did something similar, but it was more of a simulation by marshaling objects by reference. And I can think of a couple of more ways to do it, but I really don't want to manually store the mapping between the thread and the object myself. Isn't there something similar to TransactionScope for threads in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)? I am not too intersted in dealing with the hardship of syncronization and avoiding the race conditions.

PS: If that's not available, can I do it at least for an [application domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain) without static variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [ThreadStatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) attribute that you can put on a static field. From there, you can build whatever thread-specific data you desire. However, you won't be able to access the data from another thread (by thread ID for example).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `[ThreadStatic]` (already mentioned), in .NET 4.0 there is [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) - which is *broadly* similar, but is a read-only thread-specific store that uses  delegate-based initialization.

While the value *itself* is read-only, this could be a reference to a mutable object, providing thread-specific object models.

An advantage of `ThreadLocal<T>` is that it doesn't have to be bound to a static field - it could be used (for example) in the middle of a lambda body. But if you don't need this, `[ThreadStatic]` is simpler.